# Which router port address should respond with time to live exceeded in transit message?

Tags: ping, traceroute, icmp

Given the following situation:

```
PC --- |aa  RTR1  bb| --- |aa  RTR2  bb| --- |aa  RTR3  bb| etc
```

Each of the `|aa rtr bb|` is meant to be a router with two ports `aa` and `bb`.

When I do a trace route from my PC, which router port address should respond with time to live exceeded in transit message?

I seem to remember being taught to think of the router as being in as many parts as ports, so that in my scenario when `aa` is forwarding the packet to `bb` and decrements the TTL to 0, it will be the address of the `aa` port in the failure message.  I am trying to find the definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each router sends you the ICMP packet using `aa` and not using `bb`, the packet it sends will have `aa`'s address and not `bb`'s.

The router generates an ICMP packet and sends it to you. The source address the packet will have is the source address that this packet is sent from, `aa`'s address.